# Getting TypeError: b'lliks' is not JSON serialize

Tags: python, json

Write a function named `variable_get` that takes a string as a parameter representing part of a path of a url and returns the response of an HTTPS GET request to the url `https://google.com/input` as a string where `input` is the `input` parameter of this function

```
import urllib.request
def variable_get(input):
     x = "https://google.com/" + input
     response = urllib.request.urlopen(x)
     html = response.read()
     return html
```

I am getting TypeError: b'lliks' is not JSON serialize. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example of `input`?!

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this code? Please post the exact error message and the traceback.

Comment: That error message comes from calling `json.dumps()`, which doesn't appear anywhere in this function.

Comment: give us your trace stack. which line of code is the error?

Comment: please add response.headers['content-type'] and print it and comment it here.. because what it means is that the content its not application/json and you are forcing it to encode it else use response.json() or response.text

Comment: Also make sure that the url you are using is encoded properly. if the case your url is returning json format check if its valid JSON first.

Comment: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sandbox/python/run_function.py", line 93, in 
call_all(submission_file_path, function_name, all_inputs_filename, results_filename, written_filename)
File "sandbox/python/run_function.py", line 78, in call_all
json.dump(all_results, results_file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 178, in dump
for chunk in iterable:
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 427, in _iterencode
yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 324, in _iterencode_list
yield from chunks
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 403, in _iterencode_dict
yield from chunks
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 436, in _iterencode
o = _default(o)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: b'lliks' is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request
import json

def variable_get(input):
  uri = "https://google.com/input" + input
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(uri).read().decode()
  html = json.dumps(response)
  return html
```

The main take away from this code is the function `json.dumps`, converts it into a json string. For info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: I'm pretty new so I will definitely keep this in mind, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for improving your answer :)